# How to remove nth-1 array index in Javascript while doing Excel export

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, export-to-excel

How do I remove Nth-1 rows from an array?
I am trying to export my records in Excel but am getting some html code in my Excel file. The reason for this is I am trying to remove that row but am not able to delete that particular row, because that row is dynamically changing.
I am getting data in an array while checking it in debug mode.
Can anyone help me with how I can  remove total length of Array-1? For example,  if I have 40 records then I want remove **39th** position.

This is my JS Code:

```
    [![$(function () {
        var exportFlag = false;
        var reportGrid = $(time.report.gridId);
       if (reportGrid.length > 0) {
            $(time.report.gridId).data("kendoGrid").bind("excelExport",
                function(e) {
                    if (!exportFlag) {
                        var sheet = e.workbook.sheets\[0\];
                        var columns = e.sender.columns;

                        e.preventDefault();
                        exportFlag = true;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            e.sender.saveAsExcel();
                        },
                            1000);
                    } else {
                        // e.sender.hideColumn(0);
                        //e.sender.hideColumn(e.sender.columns.length + 1);
                        exportFlag = false;
                    }
                });
});][1]][1]
```

---

```
onExcelExport: function (e) {

            setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 1000);
            e.sender.hideColumn("OutIp");
            e.sender.hideColumn("InIp");
            var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
            var rows = sheet.rows;
            var rowIdx, colIdx, cells, cell;

            for (rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rows.length; rowIdx++) {
                if (rows[rowIdx].type === "data") {
                    cells = rows[rowIdx].cells;
                    var color = "#ffffff";
                    if (cells[0].value === true) {
                        color = "#ff0000";
                    }
                    for (colIdx = sheet.freezePane.colSplit; colIdx < cells.length; colIdx++) {
                        cell = cells[colIdx];

                        cell.background = color;
                        //cell.value = kendo.toString(cell.value, "c");
                        if (colIdx === 4) {
                            cell.value = cell.value.Hours + ":" + cell.value.Minutes;
                        }
                        else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value.Hours !== undefined) {
                            cell.value = utcTimeToLocalTime(cell.value.Hours + ":" + cell.value.Minutes);
                        }
                        else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value === true) {
                            cell.value = "Yes";
                        }
                        else if (cell.value !== undefined && cell.value !== null && cell.value === false) {
                            cell.value = "No";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last-but-one element of any array you could do:

```
 var numberElements = yourArray.length;
 var targetElement = numbElements - 1;

 // second parameter is number of elements to remove
 yourArray.splice(targetElement, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks..Hektor it's working fine I changed

var targetElement = numbElements - 2;